# Write down the required recursive function(s) in Scheme programming language to compute the following series

Tags: recursion, scheme

recursive function(s) in Scheme programming language to compute the following series

[image]

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged as a way to share knowledge, but it still has to be a well-asked question that might help someone in future. With this question, all the interesting information is hidden behind an image, meaning it will be impossible for search engines or visually-impaired readers to understand it.

Comment: thanks, @amalloy  for your suggestions. I will improve it

Answer (score 0):

```
//power function
(define (power a b)
     (if (zero? b) //base case
      1    
     (* a (power a (- b 1))))) //or return power of a,b

// sum function for series

    (define (sum n)
     (if (< n 3) //base case 
         0.5
       (+ (/  (power (- n 1) n) (power n (- n 1))) (sum (- n 2 ))  ))) //recursion call


>(sum 10) // call sum function here .
```